# Connect mongodb remotely

Tags: mongodb, remote-access

I have installed mongodb in a VM. Can anyone tell how to config the mongodb to connect it remotely from my local machine.

Please find the config file :

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\MongoDB\db
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\MongoDB\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Do it need to use the VM IP address in place of bindIp ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `bindIp` to `0.0.0.0` so then you can connect to mongo via VM IP's

Comment: Thanks @michelem. I have set bindIp to 0.0.0.0 and started the mongo database. Connecting successfully within VM but facing connection timeout in local machine.

Comment: Check you can reach VM from local